# Pandas df.drop() Method Won't Execute but Works?

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to drop rows from csv_file if the date in the row is greater than or equal to 80 days.

Here is the CSV_FILE: (all is read and set as strings inside CSV_FILE)

```
2019-05-01 | 14

2019-05-02 | 16

2019-05-03 | 2

2019-05-04 | 3

2019-05-05 | 3

2019-05-06 | 6

2019-05-07 | 14

2019-05-08 | 8

2019-05-09 | 5

2019-05-10 | 1

2019-05-11 | 5

2019-05-12 | 4

2019-05-13 | 1

2019-05-14 | 2

2019-05-15 | 3

2019-05-16 | 8

2019-05-17 | 2

2019-05-18 | 3

2019-05-19 | 4

2019-05-20 | 4
```

Here's what I've tried:

`s = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.to_datetime(df.index[0])).dt.days          df[s.le(80)].reset_index(drop=True).to_csv(csv_file, index=False)`

Dosen't work as the pd.Series fails for what I am trying to do. What I am currently working on is trying through df.drop() inplace but I can't figure out what is wrong and throwing an error.

The Logic implemented works but it returns the errors of either `KeyError: True` or `KeyError: False` based upon the [0] index comparrison to the boolean logic.

```
    df = pd.read_csv(GLOBAL_PATH + csv_file, sep=',', index_col=0, encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)
    # print(df)
    df.drop(df[(pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.to_datetime(df.index[0])).days >= 82].index, inplace=True)
```

I am trying to permantly delete rows from the csv_file if the date in the first index is greater than or equal to 80 days.

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

-- EDIT --

For anyone still looking. Ian Thompson did answer the question and this is what the final code looks like for what I am doing (Working Code at Top). I did also include all other code that I had been working through for this problem in case it helps anyone else in future.

```
def remove_old_data(csv_file):
    # WORKING CODE
    df = pd.read_csv(GLOBAL_PATH + csv_file, sep=',', index_col=0, encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)
    # print(df)  # Before Removal
    df.drop(df.loc[(pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.to_datetime(df.index)).days >= 180].index, inplace=True)
    # print(df)  # After Removal

    # Appended to CSV_FILE
    df.to_csv(GLOBAL_PATH + csv_file)

    # TEST OUT CODE
    s1 = (pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.to_datetime(df.index)).days
    print(s1, type(s1))  # Int64Index([84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65],
                         # dtype='int64', name='date') <class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'>
    s2 = (pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.to_datetime(df.index[0])).days  # Calculate the date difference
    print(s2, type(s2))  # 82 <class 'int'>
    zeroindex = df.index[0]
    print(zeroindex, type(zeroindex))  # 2019-05-01 <class 'str'>
    datestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.index[0])
    print(datestamp, type(datestamp))  # 2019-05-01 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
    print(df.loc[s1 <= 80])
    print(df.loc[(pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.to_datetime(df.index)).days <= 80])

    # TEST DROP CODE
    # df.drop(df[(pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.to_datetime(df.index[0])).days >= 82].index, inplace=True)
    # df.drop(df[df.iloc[[0]].le((pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.to_datetime(df.index[0])).days >= 90)].index, inplace=True)

    # NONE WORKING CODE / IN PROGRESS CODE
    # Just days time == (pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.to_datetime(df.index[0])).days
    # s = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.to_datetime(df.index[0])).dt.days  # Calculate the date difference
    # print(s[0], type(s[0]), type(s))  # Result -- 57 <class 'numpy.int64'> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
    # df[s.le(55)]#.reset_index(drop=True).to_csv(csv_file, index=False)
    # df2 = df.drop(axis=0, index=df.index[0], inplace=False).reset_index(drop=True).to_csv(csv_file, index=False)
    # df2 = df.loc[df.index[0]].le(40).reset_index(drop=False)#.to_csv(csv_file, index=False, header=False, sep=',')
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data that can be used along with your code to replicate your issue?

Comment: You are only wanting to delete the first row if it is `>= 80` days? Why do you use `55` in one spot and `82` in another?

Comment: Yes I will add in the csv_file I'm working with Brendan. @Ian Thompson the 55 is from old code. it should read 80 but I haven't been working with old code so it hasn't been changed.

Comment: @DenDay please see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Using the data you provided:

```
            val
date           
2019-05-01   14
2019-05-02   16
2019-05-03    2
2019-05-04    3
2019-05-05    3
2019-05-06    6
2019-05-07   14
2019-05-08    8
2019-05-09    5
2019-05-10    1
2019-05-11    5
2019-05-12    4
2019-05-13    1
2019-05-14    2
2019-05-15    3
2019-05-16    8
2019-05-17    2
2019-05-18    3
2019-05-19    4
2019-05-20    4
```

Your code:

```
s = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.to_datetime(df.index[0])).dt.days
df[s.le(80)].reset_index(drop=True).to_csv(csv_file, index=False)
```

will return an `IndexingError` because you are trying to filter rows of `df` with a single value. You can only filter the index of `df` using an object with the same index, or if using `iloc`, the same length.

Instead you should apply your logic to all values in the series, and then force all but the first to be `True` since you only care about dropping the first one.

```
# create boolean array for all values
ts = (pd.to_datetime('today') - df.index).days < 80

print(ts)

[False False False False False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]

# force all values except first to be True since we only care about dropping the first row
ts[1:] = True

print(df.iloc[ts])

# Note that the first value (2019-05-01) was dropped but nothing else

            val
date           
2019-05-02   16
2019-05-03    2
2019-05-04    3
2019-05-05    3
2019-05-06    6
2019-05-07   14
2019-05-08    8
2019-05-09    5
2019-05-10    1
2019-05-11    5
2019-05-12    4
2019-05-13    1
2019-05-14    2
2019-05-15    3
2019-05-16    8
2019-05-17    2
2019-05-18    3
2019-05-19    4
2019-05-20    4
```

To save `df` over itself with/out the first row:

```
df = df.iloc[ts].copy()
```

To save as `.csv` with same name:

```
df.to_csv(csv_file)
```

Comment: I did also post the entirety of the code I have now with you help! What you said finally fixed my issue and I greatly appreciate the help! Having the `[0]` was the cause of problems. Now I just need to figure out how to rewrite the CSV_FILE with the data dropped, preferably inplace if possible.

Comment: @Your welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider selecting it as correct and upvoting it if possible.

Comment: LOL You beat me to on the ```to_csv``` portion. Thanks so much!!! And I did up vote though I still don't have enough 'influence' for it to show.